# Layout with Irregular Images

Tags: android, image, layout

[image: Layout Image]

 I am trying to fill these boxes with graphics and adapt to different screen resolutions.
I have tried to use a mix of different layouts however, it not work.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: you can save different images for different screen use this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: you could use a RelativeLayout and position your ImageViews as you need. Use dp dimensions and place your drawables in the folder qualified accordingly (mdpi, hdpi...)

Answer (score 0):

QuiltView by Jacob Moncur - https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary

or StaggeredGridView by Maurycy Wojtowicz - https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo

Hope that libs can help you.